# Python/ Pandas If statement inside a function explained

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement

I have the following example and I cannot understand why it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def balh(a, b):
    z = a + b
    if z.any() > 1:
        return z + 1
    else:
        return z

df['col3'] = balh(df.col1, df.col2)
```

Output:

[image]

My expected output would be see `5` and `7` not `4` and `6` in `col3`, since `4` and `6` are `grater` than `1` and my intention is to `add` `1` if `a + b` are `grater` than `1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `any` method will evaluate if any element of the `pandas.Series` or `pandas.DataFrame` is `True`. A non-null integer is evaluated as `True`. So essentially by `if z.any() > 1` you are comparing the `True` returned by the method with the `1` integer.

You need to condition directly the `pandas.Series` which will return a `boolean pandas.Series` where you can safely apply the `any` method.

This will be the same for the `all` method.

```py
def balh(a, b):
    z = a + b
    if (z > 1).any():
        return z + 1
    else:
        return z
```

Answer (score 1):

As @arhr clearly explained the issue was the incorrect call to `z.any()`, which returns `True` when there is at least one non-zero element in `z`. It resulted in a `True > 1` which is a `False` expression.

A one line alternative to avoid the if statement and the custom function call would be the following:

```python
df['col3'] = df.iloc[:, :2].sum(1).transform(lambda x: x + int(x > 1))
```

This gets the first two columns in the dataframe then sums the elements along each row and transforms the new column according to the lambda function.

The `iloc` can also be omitted because the dataframe is instantiated with only two columns `col1` and `col2`, thus the line can be refactored to:

```python
df['col3'] = df.sum(1).transform(lambda x: x + int(x > 1))
```

Example output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     7
```